# React Redux, component internal state sync

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is a bit complicated so I'll try to put it as simple as possible.

I have a pretty much complicated reusable component in my app.
Basically, it is a large table with many editing options.
Since this component should be reusable, my thought was that it should manage it's own state.
It also makes sense because this component's business logic is pretty much complicated, and by using redux, I'll probably have to repeat some crazy boilerplates.
On the other hand, this component should be able to have some default data loaded to, and finally, this component is in some cases a **part of a form**, so I sohuld be able to extract it's data and send it to the server.
Redux can really help with the last two tasks - if I had an easy way to store all component changes in the store, I could easily load the default data from there (because my component will be fully controlled), and it will also be easy to extract data from the store when sending to server.
Although, it has a lot of boilerplate, and I'm not feelinng comforotable to write a componenet specific logic in my reducers, since ideally, they could manage themselves.
Any more ideas about that?

I had one idea that seems to be working, though I am not sure how good it is:

1. Have a "dataKey" prop to handle default data prop changes, and derive the state from the data
2. Use some submit callback to extract the data and send to server

Any more thoughts will be very helpful, thakns!

Comment: You haven't laid out a compelling use-case for Redux. Quite the opposite actually; since you're just talking about one component, it will be much simpler to store all relevant state in that component (`this.state` and `this.setState()`). Redux will be handy for something like a single-page app where a global app state can change in many different places. Start implementing, and when you run into bugs feel free to post a more concrete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's hard to provide an extract answer as your question is kind of abstract. But since you are just looking for ideas, this is just an idea which you can try to incorporate with the actual use case.*

In this kind of scenario, I would first distinguish my actual data and UI state. Then I will write my component as a controlled component of actual data with the usual `value` and `onChange` props. The UI state will be kept in the internal state of the component and it will either be derived from the initial props or initialized with a default value. When the user interacts with the component, if the change affects only the internal state, we can just use `setState` to update the state. If it affects data also, we can fire `onChange` prop also accordingly. This way we can keep the actual data in the redux store, but still, keep component specific logic in the component.

As an example, let's say we want to make a text label component with in-line/in-place editing support. I would still keep the props of this component similar to the default HTML input element as `value` and `onChange`. But the flag that indicates whether to render a text or input element with 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons will be kept in the component as `isEditMode`. Initially, we can always keep `isEditMode` as `false`. But when the user clicks on the text, we change it to true, so that component will render elements for editing and hide the label. While the user changes the text we can keep that intermediate value also in UI state. But when the user clicks the 'Submit', we can fire `onChange` with the new value in state and change `isEditMode` also to false. Likewise, we can keep the component as a control component but still use the component state to manage intermediate UI states.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting. I will try to figure it out tommorow and accept this answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: It seems to be the missing part of the puzzle, thakns!